# concat string with result of regular expression python

Tags: python, regex

A maya ascii file contains lines of instructions as follows.

```
...
createNode transform -n "pCylinder1";
createNode mesh -n "pCylinderShape1" -p "pCylinder1";
    setAttr ".vif" yes;
    setAttr ".uvst[0].uvsn" -type "string" "map1";
createNode transform -n "pPlane1";
    setAttr ".t" -type "double3" 7.3666236108700112 0 -4.2288466031573595 ;
createNode mesh -n "pPlaneShape1" -p "pPlane1";
    setAttr ".uvst[0].uvsn" -type "string" "map1";
    setAttr ".cuvs" -type "string" "map1";
createNode transform -n "pTorus1";
    setAttr ".t" -type "double3" -0.47688973199150198 0 -10.843417358550912 ;
...
connectAttr "polySphere1.out" "pSphereShape1.i";
connectAttr "polyCube1.out" "pCubeShape1.i";
connectAttr "polyCylinder1.out" "pCylinderShape1.i";
connectAttr "polyPlane1.out" "pPlaneShape1.i";
connectAttr "polyTorus1.out" "pTorusShape1.i";

...
```

Out of these lines, I need to search for a line which will look like any
of the below lines.

```
createNode transform -n nodeName -p "FG";
createNode transform -n nodeName -p "BG";
createNode transform -n nodeName -p "MG";
```

what regular expression should i use to find any of the above.

Comment: You need to put a little bit more effort into the question. Right now it's next to impossible to understand.

Comment: ok. i need to concat result of a search ( it could be FG|BG|MG ) with a known string. Having gotten it, now i need to search this string. in the above example line2 is known. zam is unknown, ie. line can contain either FG, BG or MG. say                           line = "createNode transform -n \"water\" -p \"FG\";"

Comment: Try showing example input and the corresponding expected output.

Comment: line = "createNode transform -n \"water\" -p \"FG\";"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the best I can do with your description:
*i need to concat result of a search ( it could be FG|BG|MG ) with a known string*

```
import re

line = "createNode transform -n \"water\" -p \"FG\";" 

m = search(r'(FG|BG|MG)',line)
if m:
    result = m.groups()[0]

    # What do you want to concat it to? 
    known_string = "known_string" + result
```

*"now i need to search this string.* What for?  you already searched it.
*"zam is unknown* - No it is not, it is the result of `re.compile()`

Sorry, I can't go further with your description

Comment: input --> 
    line = "createNode transform -n \"water\" -p \"MG\";"  
    zam = re.compile(r'(\" -p \")(FG|MG|BG)(\")')  
    if re.search(zam,line):  
        print 'found'

Comment: i apologise for not able to be clear. this is what i needed. thank you